# WooCommerce - unable to show shipping address fields in checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Been searching around for a while on this, tried all the suggested resolutions to no avail.

I have a shipping zone added with a shipping method attached to it. Selecting the country at checkout but still no option to set delivery address. Also, following a suggestion I saw on another question, I added the following code to try and force it to display 'ship to different address':

```
add_filter('woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_true', 999);
```

This did not work either. The products are all set up as physical products.

To rule out any theme/template issues, I have tried this on a clean WP/WC install and am getting the same results.

Seems I am missing something obvious?!

Comment: try to go shipping->shipping-option and check if you are using  Force shipping to the customer billing address if so just change it to  Default to customer billing addres

Comment: Yes checked that, forgot to mention that step in my question. It is set to default to billing address and still the same. Can’t find a solution to this anywhere?